# @gorhom/bottom-sheet not pushing on keyboard

Tags: react-native, bottom-sheet

This is my Code

```
  const snapPoints = useMemo(() => ['25%', '25%', '60%'], []);
  const {animatedHandleHeight, animatedContentHeight} =
   useBottomSheetDynamicSnapPoints(snapPoints);

     <BottomSheetModal
    ref={bottomSheetModalRef}
    index={1}
    snapPoints={snapPoints}
    enableOverDrag={true}
    keyboardBehavior='extend'
    android_keyboardInputMode='adjustResize'
    handleHeight={animatedHandleHeight}
    contentHeight={animatedContentHeight}>
    <View style={[styles.contentContainer]}>
      
        <BottomSheetTextInput
          style={styles.input}
          onChangeText={val => setValue(val)}
          keyboardType="phone-pad"
        />
      ...
    </View>
  </BottomSheetModal>
)
```

When Focus on Input it dosen't pushes the Bottom Sheet

Inside Manifest i have added this

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to use [react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view) above BottomSheetTextInput

Comment: Tried but not working